# which features do you look forward to the most in iPhone SDK 3?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

Which of the new [features](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/sdk.html) are you looking forward to the most in iPhone SDK 3.0?

Is it one of the main advertised six new things, or something smaller? Something in the "1,000 new APIs", perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone to phone communication via bluetooth seems like it will terribly useful for some apps I am writing. No longer do you have to input all the data you want to store yourself, you can share some of it with other iPhone users.

Comment: I think offline sharing is going to be a huge feature. Especially as it will greatly expand the usefulness of Touches in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

not really a feature, but the best thing about developing the iPhone SDK further is the great frameworks that arise. there are some really, really great frameworks out there already (like the Three20 project) which will become even better with the new 3.0 SDK.

my real excitement will take over once they let us run background processes. maybe in 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Video! The ability to write decent tools for mobile video uploads is a big draw.

Answer (score 1):

MapKit by far will bring the biggest change sweeping across the app space.

My personal favorite is that we can finally easily track upload progress of large files (like images).

Answer (score 1):

I really, really want to see fixes in the camera API so that it isn't either broken (2.2.1) or forcing a switch to portrait (3.0).

Apart from that, the most useful features to me are:

1. push notifications. Great for making an app more sticky - you can let the user know that something of interest to them has happened.
2. CoreData - I've been using a third-party SQL layer, but it's a little buggy and no longer supported.
3. Peer-peer bluetooth, as the poster above said, is also useful for local data exchange.

And the least useful? Cut and paste. I actually want to disable it in my app (to discourage people from copying content) - and it doesn't look as though you can (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth phone-to-phone communication with GameKit will enable a host of currently impossible applications. Multiplayer games with no WiFi network needed and data exchange between two phones are obvious use-cases.

I'd also like to see - not currently included in the betas - a decent camera API that allowed us to customize the appearance of the capture screen, and as another poster said, have it work properly in landscape and portrait mode.